MVC - Creating an entity in the controller vs Creating an entity in the service
Which option is more correct for ASP.NET MVC - creating an entity in the controller or creating an entity in the service?
Option #1 - controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SuccessfullyCreatedPromocode(string promocodeName, decimal discount)
{
    Promocode promocode = new Promocode(promocodeName, discount);
    promocodeService.CreatePromocode(promocode);
    return View();
}

Service:
public void CreatePromocode(Promocode promocode)
{
    context.Promocode.Add(promocode);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

Option #2 - controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SuccessfullyCreatedPromocode(string promocodeName, decimal discount)
{
    promocodeService.CreatePromocode(promocodeName, discount);
    return View();
}

Service:
public void CreatePromocode(string promocodeName, decimal discount)
{
    Promocode promocode = new Promocode(promocodeName, discount)
    context.Promocode.Add(promocode);
    context.SaveChanges();
}


Very broadly - try to keep your controller as lean as possible - therefore, in most cases and without knowing all the details of your environment / system, I would lean towards option #2

If you are using a layer to abstract the domain (Services) then the services should be responsible for the creation of the entities. In general a good practice is to use factory methods for creating entities where the method accepts all required (non-null-able) values to validate and construct the entity via public constructor taking those arguments, leaving a protected default constructor for EF. I tend to take a DDD approach to entities, avoiding public setters for anything that isn't optional and does not have business logic dependent on it or needs external validation.

Prefer option 2. If our system is going to grow up which will have more and more business, then we'd better to make our Controller be as clean as possible and put all business logic into services. Here, creating new Promocode can be recognized as business logic -- creating data model. In the future, it might become more complex to create such an object, it might requires to calculate based on the discount and name ahead, then we might have another method named as "PreparePromocode", then this shall be a new method in the service. So that put all these codes in Service will bring benefit

One can't give universal guidance for questions like these, because the most appropriate code organization depends on context and the goals you may have formulated for a code base.
Some applications (e.g. microservices) are small, and some are large. Some are just CRUD applications, while others implement complex logic. Some serve millions of users, and others only a handful. Some need to last for decades, while others may be intentionally short-lived.
You may, however, consider such qualities as coherence and roles.
Regarding coherence, as Kent Beck wrote:

"Things that change at the same rate belong together. Things that change at
different rates belong apart."

So if the Promocode class changes together with Service, then option #2 seems more appropriate. The drawback, however, is when you need to pass more that two values through layers. How many method arguments are too many?
Not a lot (approximately four, I'd argue). If you have more data that you need to pass through, you might consider introducing a parameter object. Would a class like Promocode be appropriate (which might suggest option #1)?
This is where a question about roles may be relevant.
What role does Promocode play? Is it an Entity to be used with Entity Framework? If so, it belongs together with the rest of the data access layer/area of the code base. On the other hand, if you also use it as a Data Transfer Object between areas, it takes on more than one responsibility, which may not always be appropriate.
While it can be a good idea to model different roles with different classes, it typically leads to a lot of code to map between representations, and it's not a given that that's always warranted.
Without context, I'd lean towards option #2, but new information could change that choice.
